# Suitable metric for comparing overlap of intervals

Tags: metric

I am trying to compare two methods but I am looking for an appropriate metric. I have two methods which both infer stop-locations for a person - each using a different type of data. A stop-location is represented as a time interval. For example, consider the following scenario:

```
Method A:
09:00-09:30
09:40-10:00

Method B:
09:00-09:14
09:15-09:29
09:38-10:00

Ground truth:
09:01-09:30
09:38-10:00
```

In the above example, the ground truth is that the person visited two stop-locations for 29 minutes and 22 minutes. The first method is a little off around the start/stop-times. The second method is better at getting start/stop-times correct, but splits the first stop-location into two pieces.

I am interesting in comparing Method A to Method B, determining which is better at inferring the ground truth.

One possibility would be to simply compute the fraction of minutes where each method predicts a stop-location where there is none, and the fraction of minutes where each method predicts no stop-location where there is one. One could for example use the F1-score for the metric then.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "better": there is no golden, universal statistical procedure to tell you which errors matter more. *You need to tell us.*  What is the cost or harm in erring on an endpoint of an interval? In splitting an interval? In other errors?  *This information needs to be quantitative* if you wish to apply rigorous methods to incorporate it in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - you are of course absolutely right. My problem comes from the fact that by being able to choose my own metric - I also have the possibility to choose it in such a way as to help my own results look better. I was hoping somebody could give a reference to a common way of measuring such an error, so that I will not be making my results look better than they actually are.